# Converting integer variable to byte variable

Tags: java

Hello i'm learning java programming and i just had task in my book which says to convert
int varible to byte variable

```
byte b;
int i=257;
```

And when i convert int to b

```
b=(byte) i;
```

Output is 1 ?
How it can be one when value of byte variable goes from -128 to 127
In my book they say byte variable have range of validity to 256 ?

Comment: Which book are you reading? `byte` in Java is always signed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
257 == 00000000000000000000000100000001 (as integer which holds 32 bits)
  1 ==                         00000001 (byte holds only 8 bits)
```

Comment: You can even test that in Java itself, if you preprend `0b` to the binary numbers. Ex: `System.out.println(1 == 0b00000001);`

Answer (score 2):

Because it can store any number from -128 to 127. A byte is always signed in Java. You may get its unsigned value by binary-anding it with 0xFF.

Example:

```
int i = 234;
byte b = (byte) i;
System.out.println(b); // -22
int i2 = b & 0xFF;
System.out.println(i2); // 234
```

Answer (score 2):

The key here is to look at the bits.

`int i = 257` gives us this set of bits (leaving off leading zeros):

```
b100000001
```

That value requires nine bits to hold (`int` has 32, so plenty of room). When you do `b = (byte)i`, it's a *truncating cast*. That means only what *can* be held by the byte (eight bits) is copied to it. So that gives us the lower eight bits:

```
b00000001
```

...which is the value `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The range of `256` is because it can store *any number from* `-128` all the way to `127`. The difference between these two numbers is `256`. The value of `1` has occurred thanks to `overflow`, where you've attempted to store a value that can not be accurately represented with `7` bits and `1` sign bit.

Answer (score 0):

its because byte range is from -128 to +127

Please check this link why byte is from [-128 to 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621067/why-is-the-range-of-bytes-128-to-127-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`-128 0 127`, So range is 256.

```
-2^7 to 2^7-1
```