# A byte can store values range -128 to +127 then I don't understand what's going on here?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class First{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte a = (byte)257;
    System.out.println(a); // output : 1
  }
}
```

I am new to Java and I do not know how am I getting an output of 1 here, can anyone explain it ?

Comment: `257&0xff` is 1. `0xff` is the pattern of bits supported by a single byte. What did you expect the result to be?

Comment: For more information, this question has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808612/converting-integer-variable-to-byte-variable

Answer (score 1):

Here, binary system plays it's role. Binary code for 257 is 100000001. Now as you already know that byte occupies 1 byte memory (8 bits). This means that a byte variable can only store 8 zeroes and ones. Since in the binary code of 257 (100000001), we have 9 bits (zeroes and ones), compiler will automatically try to convert into 8 bits. For truncating, it will take 8 bits from the right and finally what will be stored in the byte variable stored will be 00000001 (the leftmost 1 is truncated). Now 00000001 is the binary code of 1 so 1 is stored in your variable a. Thus, a is displayed.

I hope you got what I want to say.