# conversion datatype assign in java

Tags: java, type-conversion

I don't understand why i should use {b=(byte) i} or {i =(int) d} this to conversion . Please can say me cordially why it happens in conversion. My sample code below.

```
public class Conversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte b;
        int i = 257;
        double d = 323.142;
        System.out.println("\n Conversion int to byt");
        b = (byte) i;
        System.out.println("i and b "+i+ " after "+b);

        System.out.println("\n Conversion int to byt");
        i = (int) d;
        System.out.println("d and i "+d+ " after "+i);

    }

}
```

Comment: And I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`byte` have range from `-128 to 127` if you exceeds its limit you have to explicitly cast it to `int`
the same way `int` have range and if it exceeds from its range you have to explicitly cast it

if we have value of `byte` in between the range of `-128 to 127` there is no requirement of explicitly cast it to `int`

for more help i have follow link which will guide you

1. [Oracle description about primitive data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
2. [Why is the range of bytes -128 to 127 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621067/why-is-the-range-of-bytes-128-to-127-in-java)
3. [Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing "Widening Primitive Conversion" and "Narrowing Primitive Conversion".

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3