# When do I have to cast to byte when initialize a byte array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, int, type-conversion, byte

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Bed {
    private String bedfn;
    private int bytes_snp;
    private int nindiv;
    private long bedsize;
    private int nsnp;
    private byte[] magicBytes;

    public Bed(String bedfn, int bytes_snp, int nindiv) {
        this.bedfn = bedfn;
        this.bytes_snp = bytes_snp;
        this.nindiv = nindiv;
        bedsize = (new File(bedfn)).length();
        nsnp = (int) ((bedsize - 3) / bytes_snp);
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        magicBytes = new byte[] {0x6c, 0x1b, 0x01};
    }

    //...

    public OutputStream writeBytes(OutputStream fileStream, byte[] bytes) {
        try{
            fileStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileStream;
    }

    public OutputStream writeBytes(OutputStream fileStream) {
        return writeBytes(fileStream, magicBytes);
    }

    public OutputStream writeBytes(String filename, byte[] bytes) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        BufferedOutputStream fileBufferedOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        return writeBytes(fileBufferedOutput, bytes);
    }


    public OutputStream writeBytes(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return writeBytes(filename, magicBytes);
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filename = "/Users/kaiyin/personal_config_bin_files/workspace/rbed2/inst/extdata/test.bed";
        Bed bedobj = new Bed(filename, 2, 6);

        OutputStream outputStream = bedobj.writeBytes("/tmp/x.bed");
        try{
            ///////////////////////////////////////
            outputStream.write(new byte[] {(byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff});
        } finally {
            outputStream.close();
        }

    }
}
```

There are two byte array initializations (marked with ///////), in the first I didn't cast, in the second I have to, otherwise I get this error:

```
Error:(194, 45) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```

Why?

Answer (score 6):

`0xff` does not fit in the range of representable numbers in the `byte` type. The maximum value that fits in a `byte` is `127` where as `0xff` represents `255`. Therefore you need a cast in this case.

When the number is representable, for instance in the first case where you assign `0x6c` the Java compiler accepts it without a cast after applying a narrowing conversion from `int` to `byte`.

When the `integer` value is narrowed to a `byte`, all bits except the lowest representable by the target type are discarded. This means that for the integer `0xff` which is `00000000000000000000000011111111`, the lowest 8 bits are taken, resuling in the byte `11111111` which is `-1`. Therefore, the conversion changed the value *and* the sign of the initial number.

Answer (score 2):

That's because 0x01 is a Hex number that fits into a byte already, but 0xFF doesn't, so the compiler is telling you that you may lose information. So you need to explicitely cast it from int, to byte.

Answer (score 1):

The range of the type `byte` is from [-128 to 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621067/why-is-the-range-of-bytes-128-to-127-in-java). So a number like `0x6c` (which is 108 in decimal) is range. But `0xff` (which is 255) exceeds that range and it needs to be casted to get the corresponding byte value: *-1*.